# Get Initial Text value of AJAX-Loaded Drop-Down list

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Not exactly sure how to ask this, but let me give it a shot.

I have a drop-down list that is dynamically loaded at page load using AJAX/PHP called `dpdAccountsList`.

```
<select id="dpdAccountsList" onchange="AccountItem_Change(this);">
```

One of the functions called during the `onchange` event retrieves the "text" value of the selected item and writes it to a "hidden" input field on the HTML form for later retrieval.  This works.

```
function setAccountNameText(selectedAccount){
    var ptext = selectedAccount.options[selectedAccount.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("hAccountText").value = ptext;
}
```

The issue I'm having is getting the initial "text" value of the drop-down list without the user selecting a new one to trigger the change event.

I've tried about everything I can find, but no luck.

Is there a way to pass the html select object to the `onclick` event of a button similar to the `onchange(this)` that would allow me to work with the same object passed as referenced by `this` when called as an event for the select object?

Or is there a way to reference this object to get the "text" value of the selected item?

Or is there a way to ensure the first item retrieved by the database is the selected item?

My head hurts from this one.  I'm sure there is an easy answer, but I guess I can't see the forest for the trees at this point.

Thanks for you help.  Hopefully my rambling makes sense to someone.

I'd be happy to give more details if needed.

Comment: Cant you just alter the php which is creating the form to insert the value there when the page is generated?

Comment: miknik:  that may do the trick...I'll have to try that.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hmm, in jquery, you'd just trigger the .change event when the dom is ready and it would pull details like the user had selected something. Theres obviously a way to do it in raw longhand javascript, but someone else will have to explain that, as I've long forgotten how to do longhand javascript after being spoiled rotten with jquery ;)

Comment: miknik - I took your suggestion and modified the PHP code to include creating the hidden input field "hAccountText" and assigning the value.  Works like a charm.  Thanks.   If you want to add your comment as a solution, I will be happy to give you the credit by marking it as the answer.